# Final Cut Pro X stopped outputting to an Intensity Pro

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, osx, blackmagic

Final Cut Pro X stopped outputting to my Intensity Pro card.  Resolve sends video to it fine, so I assume it's in working order.

I have the latest OSX, latest Final Cut Pro X, and the latest "Desktop Video Utility".  What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've quit everything that could be using the Blackmagic card, I've rebooted etc, but FCPX video will not display on this screen.

Thanks!

-neil